# Headers css/bootstrap issues, strange

Tags: php, html, css, header

I do not understand what is going on here.

This is my file-data "structure":

[image]

Over here is the content of my folder "css"

[image]

So, in my program: this files"estudiante.php","editar.php" and "hola.php" got the same header. Take a look:

```
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
```

The problem is that i could not link the file "estilos.css"  from the "css" folder because i was given some errors while i was checking the inspect element tool using chrome:

[image]

But it is strange, because i wrote this line on my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

That line makes my page responsive, but those commands are in my estilos.css file.. i don get it, take a look:

[image]

So, estilos.css doesnt appear in my code but the header uses the content and makes my website responsive?. I dont understand this mates :(

Comment: I don't see the `<link>` to `estilos.css` in your HTML. What is the path you're using? It's possible you have a slash at the beginning which is making the browser look one folder up from your project folder on localhost. I'm guessing this is what you're using `href="/css/estilos.css"` instead of `href="css/estilos.css"` (no `/` at the beginning). FWIW, remove the duplicate `<meta>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your file naming conventions. It looks like you're hiding file extensions, since `bootstrap`, `bootstrap.min`, etc don't have `.css` on the end, but `estilos.css` does. It's possible your file is actually named `estilos.css.css` and you aren't aware.

https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/

Comment: Nice observation! Missed that myself.